# Create a regular graph with the same degree sequence in python. Is it possible?

Tags: python-2.7, graph-theory, network-analysis

I have a graph with some degree sequence. I want to create a regular graph with the same degree sequence using python for calculating small world propensity. Is it possible? Can anybody help me do this?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking for. The definition of "regular graph" that I know is that all vertices have the same degree ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph)). In your problem statement, you say you have a graph with some degree sequence and you want to construct a regular graph with the same degree sequence. I don't see how this can be possible. If the input graph is non-regular, then its degree sequence will necessarily be different from the degree sequence of a regular graph. Can you clarify what you mean?